# Can't write to /tmp in systemd service with PrivateTmp=true

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-service

My apache2 service has `PrivateTmp=true`. When the service first starts it works fine, but after a few days, writing to /tmp fails with "no such file or directory". To debug I've tried running `nsenter -t <apache-pid> -m bash` and I've confirmed that `/tmp` exists, but `mkdir /tmp/test` fails with "no such file or directory". I'd rather not remove the `PrivateTmp=true` directive.

If I restart the service it starts working again.

The mount line for /tmp inside says it is mounted to /dev/nvme0n1 which seems odd to me, but that is the case both when /tmp is working immediately after starting the service and when it is not writable.

Anyone know why /tmp suddenly becomes unwritable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

I had `tmpreaper` enabled and configured to clean up old files and directories under `/tmp`. I didn't have an exclude rule for `/tmp/systemd-private-*`, so tmpreaper was deleting the private tmp directory for apache2.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it `PrivateTmp=true` forbids exactly what you tried when you were debugging. The daemon will create it's own subdirectory and change it's namespace accordingly.

As your problem only occurs after some time I have the following advice:
Make sure the application cleans up and does not store large files in the virtual `/tmp` directory. As far as I know this directory is using RAM, no persistent file system. You have limited space here.

You might want to log the /tmp directories size for a while. If it keeps growing that's the issue.

Comment: ??? /tmp is a normal direcory with specific right it is in the /etc/fstab file.  So, this statement seems false to me.